# Cannot reach quarkus application on host from inside docker container

Tags: java, linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, quarkus

This is not a duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach). I have already attempted the suggestions in the aforementioned thread, and I know how to fix this problem in general. This problem seems to be specific to quarkus applications. I manage to make everything work except for the quarkus server.

**Context**

1. I have obtained a quarkus application template from https://code.quarkus.io/, of which includes a shell file called `mvnw`, which I can use to start a development server by executing `./mvnw quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Dquarkus.http.port=9000 -Ddebug=9001` in the host terminal.
2. I can now go to `http://localhost:9000` in the browser. I can also do `curl localhost:9000` and see that I get the HTML/CSS/JS code.

**Issue**

I cannot reach the quarkus server from within a docker container. I have tried:

1. Run a base `curl` container: `docker run --rm -it --name curl --entrypoint sh curlimages/curl:latest`
2. From within the container I attempt the following:

   - `curl host.docker.internal:9000` -> Connection refused
   - `curl localhost:9000` -> Connection refused
   - `curl (the machine host name here):9000` -> Operation timed out (this happens for all ports)
   - Run the container with `--network=host`, and use `curl localhost:9000` -> Connection refused
   - Various other suggestions from the post mentioned at the top, but all get connection refused

*However*, I can connect to the JVM debug port using `curl host.docker.internal:9001` (Empty reply from server), and I can also connect to a Python http fileserver (hosted from host) using the `host.docker.internal` hostname. It seems to be that it is only the quarkus server that I cannot connect to.

**What I want:** A reliable way to connect to the host's quarkus container from within a docker container

**System info**

- **OS:** Windows 11 21H2 22000.493 , but I do everything within WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS).
- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-10850H

Comment: `none of them work` <=  [This does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Do you get a connection refused error ? a tcp close/reset ? a "bad address" or whatever DNS error ? an http redirect to your online banking site ? ... Please edit your question to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @Zeitounator My apologies, I have updated the question now

Comment: Did you check you don't have a firewall rule in <whatever manages that on windows> or a specific configuration in your quarkus server that would allow connections only from localhost (i.e. the host running it) ?

Comment: Could you try to disable the IPV6 on your wsl2 and repeat your test? ```sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1 &&
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
``` I had similar issues and this solved the problem for me. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @FelipeWindmoller Thank you so much! That was the problem. I guess `host.docker.internal` resolves to an IPv4 address, while the java/quarkus application uses IPv6 or something? I guess I have to read up on such. However, I found out I could do `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` to make Java use IPv4 in general, which also solves the issue. I got it from here: https://superuser.com/questions/453298/how-to-force-java-to-use-ipv4-instead-ipv6. If you submit your comment as an answer I can check it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to disable the IPV6 on your wsl2 and repeat your test?

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

I had similar issues and this solved the problem for me.